# Taxonomy returns invalid taxonomy error when using get_terms()

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have registered a custom taxonomy.Please find the code below

```
function register_taxonomy_state() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'States', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'State', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search State' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All States' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent States' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent States:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit State' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update State' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New State' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New State Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'State' ),
    );
    $args   = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true, 
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'public'            =>true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => [ 'slug' => 'alumns-reps-states' ],
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'alumns-reps-states', [ 'alumns-reps' ], $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_state' );
```

I would like to display all terms added under this taxonomy, and for that i used following code

```
   $taxonomies = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'alumns-reps-states',
    'hide_empty' => false
) );

var_dump($taxonomies);
```

It is always returning `'Invalid Taxonomy'`  error. WHat is wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue.
It's help for me:
Change your code for this:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'alumns-reps-states', 
    'hide_empty' => false
);
$the_query = new WP_Term_Query($args);
var_dump($the_query->get_terms());
```